# Working on Angular Project and I am trying to center an auto-playing video. It ends up steering right of the screen everytime

Tags: html, angular, video, bootstrap-4

Hello StackOverflow Community,

I am working on a project in Angular so it doesn't accept some of the normal HTML Attributes for front end work. When I attempt to center a video I play, it ends up steering to the right of the screen no matter what I have tried. e.g. `<center>` , `<div style="align-content: center;">`, etc.

Below is the small block of code that functions properly in angular for auto playing the content but not when it needs to center it as well.

```
   <div style="align-content: center;">
     <video loop muted autoplay oncanplay="this.play()" onloadedmetadata="this.muted = true" width="1280" height="960">
       <source src="/assets/images/hero/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" style = "display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
     </video>
   </div>
```

This is built in Angular and Bootstrap with HTML. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try using `style="display: flex; justify-content-center; align-items: center;"` instead.

Answer (score 1):

## Try This

```
 <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
<div>
     <video loop muted autoplay oncanplay="this.play()" onloadedmetadata="this.muted = true" width="1280" height="960">
       <source src="/assets/images/hero/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" style = "display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
     </video>
</div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Can you explain in your answer how this worked or is it just a syntax thing?

Comment: Also, this doesn't work with mobile as it keeps the same width and height. Is there a way that I can have it auto adjust for the device? Im sure there is some kind of function for auto adjusting its size